# React page is automatically starting scrolled down for some reason

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, uikit, jsx

I'm creating a react app (w/o react-router) with UIKit for a portfolio, and as of yesterday when I finished my projects section, the page is now automatically scrolling down to that id, even when hosted on Netlify. The navbar has anchors to each id, but this definitely isn't causing the problem (since the whole page worked as intended before I implemented the projects section yesterday).

`/#projects` is not being appended to the web address, and I am not using any `window` functions.

I tried using the useEffect() hook with `window.scrollTo(0,0)` inside, but the page still starts at the projects section and *then* scrolls to the top with looks odd.

[This is the hosted version](https://joelc.netlify.app/) if you want to see exactly what I'm talking about.

Here's the projects component:

```
const Projects = () => {

    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(proj[0]);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="projects" id="projects">
                <div className="about-head-wrapper">
                    <h2 className="about-head heading">Projects</h2>
                </div>
                <MediaQuery minDeviceWidth={1001}>
                    <div className="projects-container">
                        <div className="projects-container-buttons">
                            <button
                                href="#!"
                                onClick={() => {
                                    setSelected(proj[0]);
                                }}
                                className="project-button"
                                key={proj[0].title}
                                autoFocus>
                                <img src={proj[0].logo} alt="" />
                            </button>
                            <button
                                href="#!"
                                onClick={() => {
                                    setSelected(proj[1]);
                                }}
                                className="project-button"
                                key={proj[1].title}>
                                <img src={proj[1].logo} alt="" />
                            </button>
                            <button
                                href="#!"
                                onClick={() => {
                                    setSelected(proj[2]);
                                }}
                                className="project-button"
                                key={proj[2].title}>
                                <img src={proj[2].logo} alt="" />
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="projects-container-splitter" />
                        <div className="projects-container-info">
                            <ProjectInfo
                                title={selected.title}
                                sc={selected.sc}
                                desc={selected.desc}
                                link={selected.link}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </MediaQuery>
                <MediaQuery maxDeviceWidth={1000}>
                    <div className="project-accordion-container">
                        <ul uk-accordion="collapsible: true; animation: false; multiple: true;">
                            {proj.map((p) => {
                                return (
                                    <ProjectAccordion
                                        title={p.title}
                                        sc={p.sc}
                                        desc={p.desc}
                                        link={p.link}
                                        logo={p.logo}
                                        key={p.title}
                                    />
                                );
                            })}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </MediaQuery>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
};
```

And here's my scss code for the component container:

```
.projects {
    height: 100rem;
    background-color: #3a4750;
    padding-top: 8rem;

    @media (max-width: 1000px) {
        height: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 5rem;
    }

    &-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 5rem 0;
        height: 70rem;

        &-buttons {
            flex: 0 0 32%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        &-splitter {
            flex: 0 0 1px;
            height: 60rem;
            background-color: white;
            transform: rotate(0) scaleY(1);
        }

        &-info {
            flex: 0 0 65%;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a look at your site. How are you building your nav bar? Is it possible you've set projects to be active by default?

Comment: There was actually an html autofocus put into one of the button elements that I missed, but thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

Update, I just found an `autofocus` that accidentally slipped past me. It was in `.projects-container-buttons` in the first button element that I was using in an old version of the projects component.

Comment: Thanks so much man! I just lost two hours to some mysterious scrolling issue... turns out it was autofocus as well. I'm using Mantine Modals which automatically traps focus, so it would scroll down to images inside the modal on load.